# How to get the Jmeter Server Agent to collect IOStats

Tags: jmeter-plugins, iostat

I have Jmeter serveragent running with sudo privileges
[sudo ./startAgent.sh --interval 1] on my server where I am trying to collect IO Stats using EXEC metric [image: screenshot attached]

During the jmx run (GUI Mode for verification) the Server Agent throws error as below:

```
ERROR   2022-02-28 16:01:35.804 [kg.apc.p] (): Problems executing: iostat -d -z
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "iostat -d -z": error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:621)
        at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:486)
        at kg.apc.perfmon.metrics.ExecMetric.getValue(ExecMetric.java:31)
        at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonMetricGetter.getMetricsLine(PerfMonMetricGetter.java:113)
        at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonWorker.processSenders(PerfMonWorker.java:268)
        at kg.apc.perfmon.PerfMonWorker.run(PerfMonWorker.java:231)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
        at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
        at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
        ... 7 more
```

The command works fine from the terminal.
[image]

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your terminal has `iostat` utility in [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) and the session which is established by JMeter doesn't know where this `iostat` utility lives so try using [`which` command](https://linuxize.com/post/linux-which-command/) to determine full path to the utility and amend your PerfMon Metrics collector to use the full path.

Also the command needs to exit and to supply **single numeric value** so you might want to amend the arguments accordingly.

More information: [How to Monitor Your Server Health & Performance During a JMeter Load Test](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test)

Comment: I'm able to get the command to work by modifying the metric parameter as : label=Disk IO:/bin/sh:-c:iostat -d -z  Now in the serveragent console I do not see the reported error. It says "INFO    2022-02-28 17:02:36.722 [kg.apc.p] (): Starting measures: exec:/bin/sh:-c:iostat -d -z" but the Metrics collector in Jmeter is not recording anything yet. What you said "Also the command needs to exit and to supply single numeric value " makes sense. This is probably the reason why it is not recording anything. Any idea how I can prune this command to get a single numeric value?